# type reference for a generic type in java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, completable-future, spring-async

I am trying to implement the Spring Async, but am facing an issue while trying to pass the class reference to the CompletableFuture.

```
public final class Test<T> {
    final String id;
    final Class<T> type;

    public static <T> Test<T> key(String id, Class<T> type) {
        return new Test<>(id, type);
    }
}
```

Now i want to create a constant and pass the class reference with type erasure.

```
public static final Test<CompletableFuture<Student>> variable = Test.key("variable", CompletableFuture.class); //compilation error

public static final Test<CompletableFuture> variable = Test.key("variable", CompletableFuture.class); //works but complaints about raw type
```

Please suggest, how can I pass the class reference while ensuring the type safety.

Comment: Probably an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to store the `Class<T> type`? How are you using it?

Comment: You can't do it with Class.  You could maybe do it with something like https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html .

Comment: This is not an XY problem, all this is a simple java question where we want to pass class type for a generic type and avoid warning "avoid raw types" in the process